# I am getting the OOM error when I try to train a model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection

I am trying to train a model. When I tried it with 6 classes it worked. Now, I am trying to train it with 12 calsses and I get the OOM error during training. The batch size is 1. I searched on the internet for a solution, but nothing worked. Can you please help me?

Comment: Could you provide your code?

Comment: I solved that, but the problem is that I get this error during training now: Invalid argument: assertion failed: [maximum box coordinate value is larger than 1.100000: ] [1.10582006]